# Can Amazon's S3 return objects summaries in date order?

Tags: java, android, amazon-s3

When I request object summaries from S3 via `amazonS3Client.listObjects()`, the list is returned in key alphabetical order.

Does anyone know how to get S3 to return the objects in date (lastModified) order, so the newest objects are returned first?

Thanks.

Comment: If you load them as a `List`, you can order them any way you like with `Comparator` after they're downloaded

Comment: thanks,yes i can order what is returned using comparator,but if i have more than 1000 items in the bucket it does not guarantee that the newest objects are returned within the first 1000,also with a mobile app i am using pagination and only requesting 20 items at a time.I would therefore require s3 to return me only the newest objects first

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Interesting Problem.
In my opinion the problem with ListObject is that you have to download the Objects, which can be in GB sizes.

There is no solution about this but i found a workaround in the .net development forum.

[Link to development forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=168210&#168210)

Answer (score 2):

Just sort the list after

**Java 8**

```
s3ObjectSummaries.sort(Comparator.comparing(S3ObjectSummary::getLastModified));
```

**Before**

```
Collections.sort(s3ObjectSummaries, new Comparator<S3ObjectSummary>() {
    public int compare(S3ObjectSummary o1, S3ObjectSummary o2) {
        return o1.getLastModified().compareTo(o2.getLastModified());
    }
});
```

Comment: This will not work if ListObject result is truncated (i.e. paginated)